# Is it possible to execute terminal commands using PHP?

Tags: command-line, php, kvm-virtualization

Is it possible to execute terminal commands using PHP? I need to display cores alloted to each VM and some other details of the virtual machine. Am using KVM. can anyone help to do so. Am using Ubuntu server 11.04. Can anyone explain with example.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598561/using-php-to-execute-terminal-commands

Comment: there is no clear idea on that

Comment: Are you looking for exact method to solve your KVM issue or the way to run terminal commands from PHP?

Comment: @saji89 i need to know how to run terminal commands in php. is there any other way to make link with KVM virtual manager by php coding ???

Answer (score 1):

you can use back-ticks, `exec` or `system` command to run terminal commands.

Here is the sample script which might help you

```
<?php

# back-ticks
$cpuinfo1=`lscpu`;
echo $cpuinfo1;
echo "\n===================\n";

#exec
echo "\n nproc details are here " . exec('nproc');
echo "\n===================\n";

#system
$cpuinfo2 = system('cat /proc/cpuinfo');
echo $cpuinfo2;

?>
```

Comment: sorry it doesn't works. It displays "===================nproc details are here =================== "

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: It displays "===================nproc details are here =================== "

Comment: Do you get any results when you open a terminal and run `nproc`?